# Dynamically create shortcodes using add_shortcode and a callback

Tags: shortcode

In the example below, `$shortcodes` is a multidimensional array with shortcode data.

```
foreach( $shortcodes as $shortcode ) {

    // Here we have the shortcode name, could be 'custom_person_john'.
    $shortcode_name = $shortcode['slug'];

    // Anonymous function should be referred to as 'custom_person_john'.
    $shortcode_name = function( $shortcode ) {

      // Build shortcode attributes.
      $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'name' => 'john',
        'type' => 'mammal'
      ), $atts );

      $markup = '<div class="'.$atts['name'].'">';
         $markup .= '<div>';
            // $shortcode should contain custom markup from the array.
            $markup .= $shortcode['html'];
         $markup .= '</div>';
      $markup .= '</div>';

      return $markup;

    };

    // Trying to register the shortcode
    add_shortcode( $shortcode['slug'], $shortcode_name( $shortcode ) );

};
```

So this is not working, but I can't grasps why. If I dump all the registered shortcodes, they don't show up in the list. Trying to load them simple echo's [custom_person_john]. I don't have errors either.

Edit: If anyone has other ideas on how to create them dynamically out of an array, feel free to suggest :)

Comment: What hook are you using to register the shortcodes? If you're just throwing this into `functions.php` I suggest maybe adding it into [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) to see if that helps.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Thanks for your help, unfortunately it's inside an init hook already.

Comment: you overwrite `$shortcode_name` the second time you use this variable. changing the name will to go a step ahead but in the shortcode function, i think you will not have access to `$shortcode['html']` so you have to do this on a other way

Comment: @mmm Thanks you're right, updated my answer. I have access to `$shortcode` inside the function. I dumped it by doing var_dump($shortcode), returns all the correct values.

Comment: you have access because `$shortcode_name( $shortcode )` construct a HTML string but `add_shortcode` need a function - from where come informations of $shortcodes ? you need to access theses informations inside the shortcode functions, I prepare a answer with a example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the shortcodes doesn't shop up in the liste because it's not a valid declaration with a valid function callback on the 2nd argument

try this to see what append :

```
// shortcode data

add_filter("shortcode_list", function ($shortcode_list) {
    $shortcode_list["slugA"] = array(
        "html" => "test html 1",
    );

    return $shortcode_list;
});

add_filter("shortcode_list", function ($shortcode_list) {
    $shortcode_list["slugB"] = array(
        "html" => "test <strong>html 2 - [slugA]</strong>",
    );

    return $shortcode_list;
});


// shortcodes declaration

add_action("init", function () {

    $shortcodes = apply_filters("shortcode_list", array());

    foreach (array_keys($shortcodes) as $shortcode_slug) {
        add_shortcode($shortcode_slug, "shortcode_callback");
    };

});


// callback function

function shortcode_callback($atts, $content = "", $tag) {

    // Build shortcode attributes.
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'name' => 'john',
        'type' => 'mammal'
    ), $atts);


    // shortcode data
    $shortcodes = apply_filters("shortcode_list", array());
    $shortcode = $shortcodes[$tag];


    // construct result of the shortcode

    $markup  = "";
    $markup .= '<div class="'.$atts['name'].'">';
        $markup .= '<div>';
            // $shortcode should contain custom markup from the array.
            $markup .= $shortcode['html'];
            //$markup .= do_shortcode($shortcode['html']); // to replace shortcodes in the "html" data


            $markup .= '<pre>';
            $markup .= print_r($atts, TRUE);
            $markup .= '</pre>';

        $markup .= '</div>';
    $markup .= '</div>';

    return $markup;

}
```

Comment: Awesome! Let me have a good look at this and get back to you. Love the fact we're still pulling data from the array.

Comment: Digg it, did some tweaks for my situation but got it working with your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Few months ago I was working on a similar thing where I had to generate [short codes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode) dynamically. But I took a different approach.

What I did was as following;

1. I registered a [short code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode) and [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) for which I had to use that dynamic [short code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode).
2. Then added [attribute](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes) for [post name (slug)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Post_Slug) in that [short code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode) to get data dynamically  to display on front end.

Here is sample code for how you can do that;

```
// Shortcode to display html in frontend
// [dynamic_shortcode name='post-slug']
function dynamic_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Get Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'name' => ''   // DEFAULT SLUG SET TO EMPTY
            ), $atts )
    );

    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'name'              =>  $name,     // GET POST BY SLUG  // IGNORE IF YOU ARE GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE IN YOUR EDITOR
        'post_type'         => 'your-post-type', // YOUR POST TYPE
        'post_status'       => 'publish', // POST STATUS
    );


    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() && $name != '' ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            $html_src = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'html_src' , true);  // GET HTML SOURCE FROM YOUR POST META

            if ( $html_src) {
                return $html_src; // RETURN HTML TO DISPLAY ON FRONT END
            }

        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
        return '<p style="color: red" >Sorry You have set no html for this slug...</p>';

    }


// Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode( 'dynamic_shortcode', 'dynamic_shortcode' );
```

Hope this might work for you as well.

Comment: Good thinking, I like the approach. I'm going to see if I can get a similar approach to work in my project. I would upvote, but can't yet :)